# Reading JavaScriptSerializer c# back in javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, json

In one of my webservice methods I serialized my object calling JavaScriptSerializer.serilize in c#. Now when that returns a string to my javascript I would like to be able to call the properties from the object. I tried, results.d.ID but that did not work. Here is what it returns. Thanks for any help.

```
 JavaScriptSerializer oSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        Inventory item = Inventories.GetInventoryByID(inventoryID);
        string jsonObject = oSerializer.Serialize(item);
```

For example I would like to get the ID out. how would I do that?

```
{"d":"{\"ID\":\"589652cf-2ccd-49c1-b457-f2793a2a2424\",\"Brand\":{\"ID\":\"b728281b-cf3c-4ee0-ba3d-a3573b886b14\",\"Name\":\"Puma1\",\"ParentBrand\":null,\"BrandChildren\":{\"IsValueCreated\":false,\"Value\":[]}},\"DateAdded\":\"\\/Date(1327695794000)\\/\",\"AddedBy\":{\"ID\":\"d6e1f2e7-f8d1-4809-aadd-4cacd5c2bc43\",\"Email\":\"mojo@yahoo.com\",\"FirstName\":\"maurice\",\"MiddleInitial\":\"l\",\"LastName\":\"bachelor\",\"Address\":\"111 main st\",\"Phone\":\"2162330333\",\"IsAdmin\":true,\"DateJoined\":\"\\/Date(-62135578800000)\\/\",\"HasPurchased\":false,\"AgreeTerms\":true,\"LastPurchaseDate\":null,\"Password\":\"maurice\",\"CompanyName\":\"sneakers101\",\"AllowEmail\":false,\"PurchaseOrders\":{\"IsValueCreated\":false,\"Value\":[]}},\"LastUpdated\":\"\\/Date(1327688594000)\\/\",\"Instock\":true,\"NumberInStock\":12,\"MainPictureUrl\":\"\",\"AlternativePictureUrl\":\"\",\"ThumbNailUrl\":\"\",\"Price\":12.99,\"Like\":0,\"Discount\":1,\"ItemReleaseDate\":\"\\/Date(568011600000)\\/\",\"ItemCondition\":\"Great\",\"Size\":12,\"ItemNumber\":3,\"IsFavorite\":false,\"Details\":\"test Details\",\"Name\":\"Test\"}"}
```

Comment: You're wrapping a JSON object in a string that's a property of another JSON object. This is unusual, I'm guessing your use of JavaScriptSerializer is wrong somehow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Inerdial said you have strange nested JSON value. If data is in format you actually want - use JSON.parse to re-parse values like:

`JSON.parse(results.d).ID`.

Comment: This will work, but it's best to fix the underlying issue: http://encosia.com/asp-net-web-services-mistake-manual-json-serialization/. Otherwise, he's going to be unnecessarily serializing and deserializing the data twice for every request.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what it's all about: [asp.net's ajax d](http://encosia.com/never-worry-about-asp-net-ajaxs-d-again/)

Comment: Are you sure? Value of `d` is a string not a json-object.

Comment: @L.B: yes, it's a string and you parse it with var MyObject = JSON.parse(d);

Answer (score 1):

```
var jsonObj = theObject; // Assuming it is parsed somehow

var embeddedJsonObj = $.parseJSON( jsonObj.d );

// embeddedJsonObj.ID is the ID you need.
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fXmQY/)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your underlying problem is the [manually JSON serialization](http://encosia.com/asp-net-web-services-mistake-manual-json-serialization/).

Since ASP.NET will automatically JSON serialize the result of your method, your manually serialized `jsonObject` string is then getting serialized a second time. That's why Alexei's answer works. jQuery deserialized it once, leaving you with a `.d` property containing a JSON string, and then `JSON.parse()` deserialized that inner JSON string.

However, that is doubly inefficient because your data is being serialized twice and deserialized twice. Instead, just do this:

```
[WebMethod]
public Inventory GetInventoryById(inventoryID) {
  return item = Inventories.GetInventoryByID(inventoryID);
}
```

Then, ASP.NET will return JSON that looks like this:

```
{"d": {"ID": "589652cf-2ccd-49c1-b457-f2793a2a2424", /* the rest of your data here */ }}
```

Which jQuery (assuming you're using jQuery) will automatically `JSON.parse()` since ASP.NET responds with an `application/json` Content-Type, and then you'll be able to index into like `results.d.ID`.